# Building a generic Object with a type parameter determined at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic, reflection

i Have the folowing Code and i call this by the function, buy i need to call it fom a Type otherType dynamic at runtime.

```
// this in code this works fine
DooClass newOne = GetInstance<DooClass>();

// The function
private T GetInstance<T>() where T : new()
{
    T item = SomeClass.Instance.GetItem<T>();
    if (item == null)
    {
       item = new T();
    }
    return item;
}
```

All the objects Have the same Parent ParentClass

```
//This is what i want to do or something like this
public void SomeFunction(Type someType)
{
   ParentClass newObj = GetInstance<someType>();
}
```

/////Solved using comment below by this

```
private ParentClass GetElement(Type theType)
{
   ParentClass item = (ParentClass)SomeClass.Instance.GetItem(theType);
   if (item == null)
   {
      item = (ParentClass)Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
   }
   return item;
}
```

and the metod in the class *SomeClass.Instance.GetItem();* to dont use generic type
use object all and now the Type is pased as parameter

Comment: You need to use reflection.

Comment: If T must inherit from ParentClass, then you should enforce it with a constraint when declaring the generic method.

Comment: So using the coments below i have modified two metods

Comment: any example of how should i doit @NickBray

Comment: private T GetInstance<T>() where T : new() where T : ParentClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

```
  ParentClass newObj = (ParentClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

`Activator.CreateInstance` -> Creates an instance of the specified type using that type's default constructor.

Comment: You'll need the overload `CreateInstance(Type) `that takes a type parameter as an argument, since you don't know the type at design time.

Comment: for parameterless constructor, generic interface is sufficient.

Comment: But how do you know what class to put in the angle brackets? My understanding is that it's being passed into the method as a parameter. Variables aren't valid in generic type definitions.

Comment: yes, the problem is what i put in the angled bracklets, creating the object at runtime is solved.

Comment: I missed that portion, neontapir is right. Updated the answer.